# How to get dynamic field count in dc.js numberDisplay?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get a count of unique records to display using DJ.js and D3.js

The data set looks like this:

```
id,name,artists,genre,danceability,energy,key,loudness,mode,speechiness,acousticness,instrumentalness,liveness,valence,tempo,duration_ms,time_signature
6DCZcSspjsKoFjzjrWoCd,God's Plan,Drake,Hip-Hop/Rap,0.754,0.449,7,-9.211,1,0.109,0.0332,8.29E-05,0.552,0.357,77.169,198973,4
3ee8Jmje8o58CHK66QrVC,SAD!,XXXTENTACION,Hip-Hop/Rap,0.74,0.613,8,-4.88,1,0.145,0.258,0.00372,0.123,0.473,75.023,166606,4
```

There are 100 records in the data set, and I would expect the count to display 70 for the count of unique artists.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(spotifyData);
totalArtists(ndx);

....

function totalArtists(ndx) {
    // Select the artists
    var totalArtistsND = dc.numberDisplay("#unique-artists");
    // Count them
    var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("artists"));
    var uniqueArtist = dim.groupAll();
    totalArtistsND.group(uniqueArtist).valueAccessor(x => x);

    totalArtistsND.render();
}
```

I am only getting 100 as a result when I should be getting 70.

Thanks a million, any help would be appreciated

Comment: To just count the unique artists you could simply use `new Set(spotifyData.map(d => d.artists)).size`.

Comment: That's correct, @altocumulus, but as I understand it, the question is how to get that to display dynamically in dc.js, in response to crossfilter filters. That would be a good sanity check to make sure the data shows the expected 70 when unfiltered.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I do need it to be dynamic and update with the crossfilter. I've done a static count and gotten the correct 70 value but it would be great if it could be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track - a groupAll object is usually the right kind of object to use with `dc.numberDisplay`.

However, [dimension.groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll) doesn't use the dimension's key function. Like any groupAll, it looks at all the records and returns one value; the only difference between `dimension.groupAll()` and `crossfilter.groupAll()` is that the former does not observe the dimension's filters while the latter observes all filters.

If you were going to use `dimension.groupAll`, you'd have to write reduce functions that watch the rows as they are added and removed, and keeps a count of how many unique artists it has seen. Sounds kind of tedious and possibly buggy.

Instead, we can write a "fake groupAll", an object whose `.value()` method returns a value dynamically computed according to the current filters.

The ordinary group object already has a unique count: the number of bins. So we can create a fake groupAll which wraps an ordinary group and returns the length of the array returned by `group.all()`:

```
function unique_count_groupall(group) {
  return {
    value: function() {
      return group.all().filter(kv => kv.value).length;
    }
  };
}
```

Note that we also have to filter out any bins of value zero before counting.

Use the fake groupAll like this:

```
var uniqueArtist = unique_count_groupall(dim.group());
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5b8we1ct/10/).

I just added this [to the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groupall).

Comment: Unfortunately the count isn't updating when I update the crossfilter, would you know how I call this on update? Thanks a mill :)

Comment: Whoops, it should update but I forgot to remove empty bins. Please see my edit above.